# Генерируемые компилятором методы – в чём смысл?

Tags: java, методы, enum

Например, методы генерируемые компилятором – values() и valueOf(String name) для перечислений (в классе [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) их нет): почему бы просто не объявить их как и другие, в классе Enum?
И где находится документация по таким методам?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что класс `Enum` ничего не знает ни об именах ваших перечислений ни об их значениях. Можно было бы вытащить их через рефлексию, но это долго. Проще и быстрее сгенерировать эти методы при компиляции

Answer (score 6):

1) Сначала была генерация дефолтного конструктора

2) Потом было решено добавить методы в `Enum`

3) Далее пришло понимание, что приходится автогенерить методы доступа для `inner class`, иначе внутренний класс будет недоступен

4) Потом решили что пора навести здесь порядок и ввели аннотации, где процессор аннотаций будет генерить методы во время компиляции, возникает хотя бы подобие управляемости генерацией методов во время компиляции

5) Потом пришел Kotlin, который возвел автогенерацию методов во время компиляции вообще в принцип.

6) ...